# How old must The Moon be?

Tags: planets, hard-science, moons, earth

Some time ago, aliens placed the Moon around Earth with every intent to deceive us about its authenticity, except for the glaring synchronization that allows for total solar eclipses, as something like a practical joke.

**What indirect evidence do we have that places the Moon's age as far back as possible?** "Indirect" as in data points not originating from the Moon itself, e.g., radiometric dating of Moon rocks.

The aliens have never tampered with Earth, only everything about the Moon (its make-up, surface topography, orbital path, etc.) meaning any lunar influences *found on Earth* are legit. The aliens ceased all tampering 2 million years ago.
The Moon is as it appears to be: a big old rock — just made to fool. There's a greater lore reason, it's just not important here.

Essentially, I'm trying to place the Moon's insertion on a timeline in my world (which helps inform the period of other events), and because nothing about the Moon can be trusted as a chronological indicator, only evidence of the Moon's presence found on Earth (or elsewhere in the solar system, too, I suppose, if any exist) can be credited.

---

All this of course means that the [protoplanetary collision with Theia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant-impact_hypothesis) didn't happen, and everything that hypothetical event precipitated is explained elsehow. (Unless it *can't be*, in which case that counts as evidence of the Moon (aw shucks), but then you'd've also proven the Theia hypothesis beyond doubt so what are you even doing here?)

Comment: For reference, [*Mutineers' Moon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutineers'_Moon) (1991) by [David Weber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Weber), first book of the [*Empire from the Ashes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_from_the_Ashes) trilogy.

Comment: Does your premise contradict itself? If the aliens put the moon there recently, then why would there be any indirect evidence of it being older? All such evidence would not be there because in your story it's not older. It reads more like you're arguing that aliens did in fact put the moon there (in this, the real universe) and asking for evidence disproving it. But that's not worldbuilding.

Comment: @causative You misunderstand what I'm asking. I'm looking for the earliest evidence of the Moon that isn't plucked off its surface. I never said the aliens put it there recently. I'm prepared to push the date back billions of years if necessary (but hopefully, "only" tens of millions).

Comment: @causative Don't lop me into the flat earther/electric universe camps. Please, I beg!

Comment: Don't know enough about the subject to write a full answer, but I know that geologists have found tidal [rhythmites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhythmite) at least 300 million years old. They are one of the data points which enable the reconstruction of the number of days in a lunar month and in a year.

Comment: Alright. Anyway, the Wikipedia article on Theia lists some evidence. Apparently the isotopes of molybdenum on Earth suggest that the water on Earth came from the outer solar system. Theia could explain why Earth's core is larger than expected. And the moon rocks retrieved by the Apollo astronauts had similar composition to Earth's crust. To fake this the aliens would have had to first probe Earth's crust to find the right composition - does that count as 'messing with' Earth or not?

Comment: @causative No, it doesn't count. Probing is not tampering, which here is the deliberate attempt to obfuscate the Moon's origin.

Comment: Any moon rocks found on Earth are part of the hoax, since the Moon...as every child knows...is made of cheese, not rock.

Comment: If the Question was about our real universe, any or all of the exposition might matter. Since this is supposed to be about a world you built, isn't it your job to write your own rules? Failing that, what's wrong with user535733's cheese, not rock, assessment?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin scifi is normally based on the real world. If evidence for the Moon pushes past the period I'm comfortable with then yeah I'd BS it (and that's what it's looking like). If not then I might have had an interesting argument to make the case to the reader. *"Well, it was strange that rhythmites only started appearing on Earth X million years ago..."* I'm not well-informed in all the disciplines where such evidence might crop up, (geology, Earth science, biology, astrophysics) which is why this site exists, and this question. Wouldn't have known unless I asked.

Comment: Have you met anyone who doubted sci-fi was based on the real world? Anyone, ever?

What on Earth - no pun intended - could 'If evidence for the Moon pushes past the period I'm comfortable with then yeah I'd BS it' mean in English?

Comment: I'd add that sci-fi is *informed by science* rather than based on it. No-one's saying we actually have warp drive or replicators in the real world (more's the pity).

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin It simply means if I don't like the answers I get then I throw out the idea and BS the explanation.

Comment: @BMF Could you run that by Stack Exchange's rules of conduct?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Show me where it says I'm obligated to incorporate the info of user answers into my work?

Comment: Not to say I don't appreciate answerers in any way. I write more answers than questions on this site, I know the work that goes into them. Under the premise of "being closely aligned with the real world" I hoped for a favorable outcome and didn't get it. ‍♂️ What I got instead was an interesting answer from a knowledgeable user and an avenue to BS down.

Comment: @BMF I would not have suggested you were obligated to incorporate the info of user answers into your work, even if I understood what that meant.' (Please, what does that mean?)

Comment: How about we run this tedious convo by rules of conduct instead?

Comment: Whether you like the answers you get is up to you. Who could dispute that?

That you throw out an idea is equally, your choice. How you throw out that idea is supposed to follow set rules.

If you do not accept that, why should you not be held to account? 

I can only guess - unpleasantly - what 'BS the explanation' means. At face value, 'BS the explanation' means to flout the rules; to deliberately disrespect whoever gave that explanation.

How can you justify your views?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin No, "BS the explanation" means I don't corroborate the ancient Moon's presence with factual data in my worldbuilding, because it didn't work for me the way I had hoped. *I BS it instead.* How I discard ideas follows no rules outside the context of SE. Do you understand now?

Comment: Sorry, BMF. Too much!

Comment: I get what you're saying @BMF. Perhaps substitute "handwave" for "BS" and you'd have sitespeak fluency.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to get really weird (and in fact avoid using any material that came from the Moon), you can try sediment analysis. I went to a talk on this a few months ago, where the speaker discussed how studying the history of sediment stratification can actually allow us to map changes in the Moon's orbit over time (implicitly showing that the Moon existed far in the past).

The logic is that the Moon plays a role in a couple periodic changes in Earth's orbit that 1) play out over timescales of tens and hundreds of thousands of years, and 2) are stable over hundreds of millions of years. Through complex processes, these changes affect sediment deposition rates; by measuring changes in those rates, you can see the fingerprints of the Moon's influence. One of the more recent papers on this is [Meyers & Malinverno 2018](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018PNAS..115.6363M/abstract), who studied the **1.4-billion-year-old** Xiamaling Formation. The most extreme studies I'm aware of actually probed as far back as **~2.5 billion years ago** ([Walker & Zahnle 1986](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1986Natur.320..600W/abstract), [Williams 2000](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000RvGeo..38...37W/abstract).

You could argue that perhaps the Moon isn't responsible for these changes. Perhaps the scientists could get adequate fits to their data if they used models involving no influence from the Moon whatsoever. On the other hand, the only folks who would know this for sure are the teams who did the work (but if you ask them, let me know!).

Comment: I thought it might be something in the geological strata, or maybe a thing more weird like something in the fossil record pointing to lunar cycles followed by ancient life. Also, my question makes no sense! *"Moon rocks found on Earth are fair game?"* I'm glad you saw past that mistake though to what I was really interested in.

Comment: (Also, with your permission I'd like to correct that about my question before any more answers pop up. I guess my intent was to say Moon rocks whose impact on Earth could be dated, and not the rocks themselves, are fair game. It's probably best to leave it out entirely to not confuse everyone.)

Comment: @BMF I suspect (but haven't confirmed) that the team which found & dated the moon rocks on Earth did so by comparing their composition with sample-return missions to the Moon... so I'd still class this evidence as derived from the lunar surface. You might be able to get similar constraints with spectrometry of the light reflected from the lunar surface, but probably with much less precision, and the observable-from-Earth lunar density places another restriction on composition, but it seems hard to imagine definitively placing meteorites origin on the Moon because of that.

Comment: However, @hde-226868 's description of the Moon's effect on sediment deposition is _fantastic_.

Comment: @BMF Yeah, I'm totally fine with you changing that -- I agree it's a weird exception to carve out. (I do appreciate you asking to change it, by the way!).

Comment: There's apparently even traces of tidal rhythms left in some of the faster-growing banded iron formations, and that dates back to the Great Oxygen Catastrophe. These jokers were really looking ahead if they arranged their prank at a time when the highest form of life on Earth was some variety of photosynthetic scum.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Especially since tidal forces push the moon gradually outward (the dinosaurs did not enjoy this cosmic coincidence)

Comment: @NoName yeah, and the rhythmites and other evidence show that change in its orbit over time. It's not so much a coincidence that it has the same angular diameter as the sun, that would have become the case at *some* point as long as it started off with a larger angular diameter. The coincidence is that they're equal while we're here to observe it.